# How can a series of Tasks be made to run in order?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task-parallel-library

I have a series of `Task`s that I want to run in order from a-z.

I would like to execute these calls synchronously `starting from 1 and ending at N`.

- **task1** DeleteSubProjects...1

  - **task1** DeleteActivities...2

    - **task1** DeleteActivityPersons...3
    - **task2** DeleteThreads...4

      - **task1** DeleteCommunicationThreadContentTags...5
      - **task2** DeleteCommunicationThreadParticipants...6
      - **task3** DeleteMessages
      - **task4**  Delete(communicationThread)
    - **task3** DeleteActivityDocuments
    - **task4** DeleteActivityNotes
    - **task5** DeleteActivityMachines
    - **task6** DeleteActivityLinks
    - **task7** DeleteActivityLinks
    - **task8** Delete(activity)
  - **task2** DeleteSubProjectDocuments
  - **task3** DeleteSubProjectNotes
  - **task4** DeleteSubProjectPersons
  - **task5** DeleteSubProjects
  - **task6** Delete(subProject)
- **task2** deleteProjectNotes
- **task3** deleteProjectDocuments
- **task4** deleteActivities
- **task5** deleteProjectPersons

here is what the code looks like

```
public async Task DeleteProject(Project project)
{

    var deleteSubProjects = UnitOfWork.Instance.SubProjectService.DeleteSubProjects(project.SubProjects);
    var deleteProjectNotes = UnitOfWork.Instance.ProjectNoteService.DeleteProjectNotes(project.ProjectNotes);
    var deleteProjectDocuments = UnitOfWork.Instance.ProjectDocumentService.DeleteProjectDocuments(project.ProjectDocuments);
    var deleteActivities = UnitOfWork.Instance.ActivityService.DeleteActivities(project.Activities);
    var deleteProjectPersons = UnitOfWork.Instance.ProjectPersonService.DeleteProjectPersons(project.ProjectPersons);

    await Task.WhenAll(deleteSubProjects)
        .ContinueWith(_ => deleteProjectNotes)
        .ContinueWith(_ => deleteProjectDocuments)
        .ContinueWith(_ => deleteActivities)
        .ContinueWith(_ => deleteProjectPersons)
        .ContinueWith(_ => Delete(project)).Unwrap();            
}
```

subprojects

```
public async Task DeleteSubProjects(IList<SubProject> subProjects)
{
    foreach (var subProject in subProjects.ToList())
    {
        await DeleteSubProject(subProject);
    }
}
public async Task DeleteSubProject(SubProject subProject)
{
    var task1 = UnitOfWork.Instance.ActivityService.DeleteActivities(subProject.Activities);
    var task2 = UnitOfWork.Instance.SubProjectDocumentService.DeleteSubProjectDocuments(subProject.SubProjectDocuments);
    var task3 = UnitOfWork.Instance.SubProjectNoteService.DeleteSubProjectNotes(subProject.SubProjectNotes);
    var task4 = UnitOfWork.Instance.SubProjectPersonService.DeleteSubProjectPersons(subProject.SubProjectPersons);
    var task5 = DeleteSubProjects(subProject.ChildSubProjects);
    var task6 = Delete(subProject);

    await Task.WhenAll(task1)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task2)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task3)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task4)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task5)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task6).Unwrap();
    //Delete(subProject);    
}
```

activities

```
public async Task DeleteActivities(IList<Activity> activities)
{
    foreach (var activity in activities)
    {
         await DeleteActivity(activity);
    }
}
public async Task DeleteActivity(Activity activity)
{
    var task1 = UnitOfWork.Instance.ActivityPersonService.DeleteActivityPersons(activity.ActivityPersons);
    var task2 = UnitOfWork.Instance.CommunicationThreadService.DeleteThreads(activity.CommunicationThreads);
    var task3 = UnitOfWork.Instance.ActivityDocumentService.DeleteActivityDocuments(activity.ActivityDocuments);
    var task4 = UnitOfWork.Instance.ActivityNoteService.DeleteActivityNotes(activity.ActivityNotes);
    var task5 = UnitOfWork.Instance.ActivityMachineService.DeleteActivityMachines(activity.ActivityMachines);
    var task6 = UnitOfWork.Instance.ActivityLinkService.DeleteActivityLinks(activity.SuccActivityLinks);
    var task7 = UnitOfWork.Instance.ActivityLinkService.DeleteActivityLinks(activity.PredActivityLinks);
    var task8 = Delete(activity);

    await Task.WhenAll(task1)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task2)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task3)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task4)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task5)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task6)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task7)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task8).Unwrap();
   // Delete(activity);
}
```

threads

```
internal async Task DeleteThreads(IList<CommunicationThread> threads)
{
    foreach (var thread in threads)
    {
      await  DeleteThread(thread);
    }
}
internal async Task DeleteThread(CommunicationThread communicationThread)
{
   var task1 = UnitOfWork.Instance.CommunicationThreadContentTagService.DeleteCommunicationThreadContentTags(communicationThread.CommunicationThreadContentTags);
   var task2 = UnitOfWork.Instance.CommunicationThreadParticipantService.DeleteCommunicationThreadParticipants(communicationThread.CommunicationThreadParticipants);
   var task3 = UnitOfWork.Instance.CommunicationMessageService.DeleteMessages(communicationThread.CommunicationMessages.Where(msg => msg.CommentOnMessageID == null).ToList());
   var task4 = Delete(communicationThread);

   await Task.WhenAll(task1)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task2)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task3)
        .ContinueWith(_ => task4).Unwrap();
}
```

Comment: ... Don't make them asynchronous in the first place?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan  I want to try this before I go and implement a cascade on delete. Not making async throws out of memory exception.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rather than calling `Task.WhenAll` and declaring a variable for each `Task`, simply `await` each one in the order you need -- for example:

```
public async Task DeleteProject(Project project)
{
    var instance = UnitOfWork.Instance;

    await instance.SubProjectService.DeleteSubProjects(project.SubProjects);
    await instance.ProjectNoteService.DeleteProjectNotes(project.ProjectNotes);
    await instance.ProjectDocumentService.DeleteProjectDocuments(project.ProjectDocuments);
    await instance.ActivityService.DeleteActivities(project.Activities);
    await instance.ProjectPersonService.DeleteProjectPersons(project.ProjectPersons);          
}
```

Now the order of the delete operations in this specific example are serialized.

Comment: This is actually what I had before but someone gave me the suggestion to do it this way because they said it takes less memory. I'm going for a cascade on delete but I want to experiment with other alternatives. Thanks for this answer,